# Tables with center alignment of vertical text in multirow

Tags: tables

Is it possible to make such table in LaTeX? And is so - what user packages I have to use?
The problem I have faced is center alignment of vertical text in colums 1 and 2

[image: sample]

```
\documentclass[a3paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{array,tabularx,tabulary,booktabs,multirow,graphicx} 
\usepackage{geometry} % Простой способ задавать поля
    \geometry{top=10mm}
    \geometry{bottom=10mm}
    \geometry{left=10mm}
    \geometry{right=10mm}

\begin{document} 

%{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Oil-Water \& Gas-Water}}
%{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Gas-Oil}}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|m{3cm}|b{3cm}|p{12cm}|p{2cm}|}
%\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{|J|J|J|J|J|J|}
\hline 
{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{ Well type }}}   & {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{System}}} & \textbf{Calculated parametr}  & \textbf{Author}  & \textbf{Limitations} & \textbf{Equation type}  \\ 
\hline  
\multirow{10}{*} & \multirow{8}{*}   & \multirow{5}{*}{Critical Rate} & Chaperon  & For vertical wells, the perforated interval, hp, is very small and the well is perforated at the top of the reservoir for water coning situations. Analytical equations are based on the equilibrium conditions of viscous forces and gravity forces. & Analitical \\  \cline{4-6}
  &  &  & Hoyland et al & Equations are based on correlation of computer simulation runs. &  \\ \cline{4-6}
  &  &  & Meyer et al & Equations are based on simplified radial flow of oil under it's own gravity head. They are generally less accurate than more rigorous methods. For gas coning, it is assumed that the gas-oil contact is depressed around the wellbore because of radial flow. For simultaneous gas and water coning, the maximum possible oil production rate is calculated assuming an optimum placement of the perforated interval. &  \\ \cline{4-6}
  & {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Oil-Water \& Gas-Water}} &  & Schols & Equations are based on correlation of laboratory experiments. For oil mostly. &  \\ \cline{4-6}
  &  &  & Chirechi & Based on the potentiometric theory of Muskat and Wyckoff using and electrical analog model. &  \\ \cline{3-6}
 &  & Post-water breakhrough & Kuo \& DesBrisay & This correlation was developed by investigating the sensitivity of water coning performance to various reservoir parameters using numerical simulation. &  \\ \cline{3-6}
 {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Vertical}} &  & \multirow{2}{*}{Breakthrough Time} & Bournazel \& Jeansen & Evaluation and modification of the plot developed by Sobocinski and Cornelius resulted in a simple analytical expression to fit the plot. &  \\ \cline{4-6}
  &  &  & Saboncinski \& Kornelius & This correlation is based on experimental data and computer simulation runs. A dimensionless plot that traces the rise of the cone apex from initial build-up to breakthrough was developed. &  \\ \cline{2-6}
  & {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Gas-Oil}} & Critical Rate & Mayer et al & Equations are based on simplified radial flow of oil under it's own gravity head. They are generally less accurate than more rigorous methods. For gas coning, it is assumed that the gas-oil contact is depressed around the wellbore because of radial flow. For ultaneous gas and water coning, the maximum possible oil production rate is calculated assuming an optimum placement of the perforated interval.
  Analytical equations are based on the equilibrium conditions of viscous forces and gravity forces.  &  \\ \cline{2-6}
  & {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Gas-Oil-Water}}  & Critical Rate & Mayer et al & Equations are based on simplified radial flow of oil under it's own gravity head. They are generally less accurate than more rigorous methods. For gas coning, it is assumed that the gas-oil contact is depressed around the wellbore because of radial flow. For ultaneous gas and water coning, the maximum possible oil production rate is calculated assuming an optimum placement of the perforated interval.
    Analytical equations are based on the equilibrium conditions of viscous forces and gravity forces. &  \\ 
\hline 
\hline  
\multirow{9}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Horizontal}} & \multirow{7}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Oil-Water \& Gas-Water}} & \multirow{2}{*}{Critical Rate} & Chaperon & For horizontal wells, the method assumes that the well is drilled near the top of the reservoir for water coning situations. &  \\  \cline{4-6}
  &  &  & Efros & Based on the equilibrium conditions of viscous forces and gravity forces. &  \\  \cline{3-6}
  &  & \multirow{2}{*}{Post-water breakhroug} & Mutalic \& Joshi & This correlation was developed by investigating the sensitivity of water coning performance to various reservoir parameters using numerical simulation. &  \\  \cline{4-6}
  &  &  & Suoza et al & Assumes the horizontal well traverses the entire drainage area, so flow beyond the ends of the well is neglected. &  \\  \cline{3-6}
  &  & \multirow{3}{*}{Breakthrough Time} & Papatzakos et al &  This solution applies only to infinite acting reservoirs. The solution is derived by a moving boundary method with constant pressure or gravity equilibrium assumed at the moving boundary. &  \\  \cline{4-6}
  &  &  & Ozkan \& Raghavan & Developed using numerical simulation. This solution applies only to infinite acting reservoirs. &  \\  \cline{4-6}
  &  &  & Suoza et al & Developed using numerical simulation, by correlating the results from many simulation runs. Assumes the horizontal well traverses the entire drainage area, so flow beyond the ends of the well is neglected  &  \\  \cline{2-6}
  & \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Gas-Oil}} & \multirow{2}{*}{Critical Rate} & Chaperon & For horizontal wells, the method assumes that the well is drilled near the top of the reservoir for water coning situations. &  \\  \cline{4-6}   &  &  & Joshi & The Equations are for short horizontal wells. They are modifications of the Meyer, Gardner, Pirson method for vertical wells. &  \\  
\hline 
\end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is possible, but colours makes it somewhat complex because `\clines` actually produce a white line in columns where there is no rule – e.g. `\cline{2-6}` is actually a full `\hline` that's white in the first column; when a cell background is coloured, you see this white line. So I had to use the `hhline` package to have multicoloured lines.
Another consequence of coloured cells is that one has to use `\multirow{n}{…}` at the end of the group of rows (with parameter –n) to see the text. Actually I used the `\multirowcell` and a few other commands from the `make cell` package.

```
\documentclass[a3paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry} % Простой способ задавать поля
    \geometry{margin=15mm}

\usepackage{array,tabularx,tabulary,multirow,graphicx, hhline}

\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}

\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[x11names, tables]{xcolor}

\newcommand\cb{\arrayrulecolor{CadetBlue1!60!}}
\newcommand\yl{\arrayrulecolor{Yellow1!35}}
\newcommand\bk{\arrayrulecolor{black}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\sffamily\centering\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.6pt}%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{!{\vrule width 1pt}c|c|m{2.4cm}|m{2.8cm}|X|c!{\vrule width 1pt}}
\Xhline{1pt}
\rowcolor{gray!30!}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{ Well type }}} & {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{System}}} & \thead{Calculated\\ parameter} & \thead{Author} & \thead{Limitations} & \raisebox{-0.45\height}{\rotatebox{90}{\thead{Equation \\type}}} \\
\Xhline{1pt}
\multicolumn{6}{c}{} \\[-2ex]
\Xhline{1pt}
\rowcolor{Yellow1!35!} & & & Chaperon & For vertical wells, the perforated interval, hp, is very small and the well is perforated at the top of the reservoir for water coning situations. Analytical equations are based on the equilibrium conditions of viscous forces and gravity forces. & \cellcolor{DarkSeaGreen1!50!}Analytical \\
\hhline{|>{\yl}->{\bk}|>{\yl}->{\bk}|>{\yl}->{\bk}|---}
\rowcolor{Yellow1!35!} & & & Hoyland \& al. & Equations are based on correlation of computer simulation runs. & \cellcolor{DarkSeaGreen1!50!}Empirical \\
\hhline{|>{\yl}->{\bk}|>{\yl}->{\bk}|>{\yl}->{\bk}|---}
\rowcolor{Yellow1!35!} & & & Meyer \& al. & Equations are based on simplified radial flow of oil under it's own gravity head. They are generally less accurate than more rigorous methods. For gas coning, it is assumed that the gas-oil contact is depressed around the wellbore because of radial flow. For simultaneous gas and water coning, the maximum possible oil production rate is calculated assuming an optimum placement of the perforated interval. \break
    Analytical equations are based on the equilibrium conditions of viscous forces and gravity forces. & \cellcolor{DarkSeaGreen1!50!}Analytical \\
\hhline{|>{\yl}->{\bk}|>{\yl}->{\bk}|>{\yl}->{\bk}|---}
\rowcolor{Yellow1!35!} & & & Schols & Equations are based on correlation of laboratory experiments. For oil mostly. & \cellcolor{DarkSeaGreen1!50!}Empirical \\
\hhline{|>{\yl}->{\bk}|>{\yl}->{\bk}|>{\yl}->{\bk}|---}
\rowcolor{Yellow1!35!} & & \multirowcell{-11}{Critical Rate} & Chirechi & Based on the potentiometric theory of Muskat and Wyckoff using and electrical analog model. & \cellcolor{Tan1!50!}Analytical \\
\hhline{|>{\yl}->{\bk}|>{\yl}->{\bk}|----}
\rowcolor{Yellow1!35!} & & \makecell{Post-water \\ breakthrough} & \mbox{Kuo \&} \mbox{DesBrisay} & This correlation was developed by investigating the sensitivity of water coning performance to various reservoir parameters using numerical simulation. &\cellcolor{Tan1!50!}Empirical \\
\hhline{|>{\yl}->{\bk}|>{\yl}->{\bk}|----}
\rowcolor{Yellow1!35!} & & & Bournazel \&~Jeansen & Evaluation and modification of the plot developed by Sobocinski and Cornelius resulted in a simple analytical expression to fit the plot. & \cellcolor{Tan1!50!}Empirical \\ \hhline{|>{\yl}->{\bk}|>{\yl}->{\bk}|>{\yl}->{\bk}|---}
\rowcolor{Yellow1!35!} & \multirowcell{-16}{\colorbox{Yellow1!35!}{\rotatebox{90}{Oil-Water \& Gas-Water}}} & \multirowcell{-3}{Breakthrough \\ time} & Saboncinski \&~Kornelius & This correlation is based on experimental data and computer simulation runs. A dimensionless plot that traces the rise of the cone apex from initial build-up to breakthrough was developed. & \cellcolor{Tan1!50!}Empirical \\
\hhline{|>{\yl}->{\bk}|-----}
\rowcolor{Yellow1!35!} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Gas-Oil } & \makecell{Critical Rate} & Meyer \& al. & Equations are based on simplified radial flow of oil under it's own gravity head. They are generally less accurate than more rigorous methods. For gas coning, it is assumed that the gas-oil contact is depressed around the wellbore because of radial flow. For simultaneous gas and water coning, the maximum possible oil production rate is calculated assuming an optimum placement of the perforated interval. \break
  Analytical equations are based on the equilibrium conditions of viscous forces and gravity forces. & \cellcolor{Tan1!50!}Analytical \\
\hhline{|>{\yl}->{\bk}|-----}
\rowcolor{Yellow1!35!}\multirowcell{-25}{\colorbox{Yellow1!35!}{\rotatebox{90}{Vertical}}}& \makecell{\colorbox{Yellow1!35!}{\rotatebox{90}{Gas-Oil-Water }}} & \makecell{Critical Rate} & Meyer \& al. & Equations are based on simplified radial flow of oil under it's own gravity head. They are generally less accurate than more rigorous methods. For gas coning, it is assumed that the gas-oil contact is depressed around the wellbore because of radial flow. For simultaneous gas and water coning, the maximum possible oil production rate is calculated assuming an optimum placement of the perforated interval. \break
    Analytical equations are based on the equilibrium conditions of viscous forces and gravity forces. & \cellcolor{Tan1!50!}Analytical \\
\Xhline{1pt}
\multicolumn{6}{c}{} \\[-2ex]
\Xhline{1pt}
\rowcolor{CadetBlue1!60!} & & \multirowcell{2}{Critical Rate} & Chaperon & For horizontal wells, the method assumes that the well is drilled near the top of the reservoir for water coning situations. & \cellcolor{DarkSeaGreen1!50!}Empirical \\
\hhline{|>{\cb}->{\bk}|>{\cb}->{\bk}|>{\cb}->{\bk}|---}
\rowcolor{CadetBlue1!60!}\cellcolor{CadetBlue1!60!} & & & Efros & Based on the equilibrium conditions of viscous forces and gravity forces. & \cellcolor{DarkSeaGreen1!50!}Empirical \\
 \hhline{|>{\cb}->{\bk}|>{\cb}->{\bk}|----}
\rowcolor{CadetBlue1!60!} & & & \mbox{Mutalic \& Joshi} & This correlation was developed by investigating the sensitivity of water coning performance to various reservoir parameters using numerical simulation. & \cellcolor{Tan1!50!}Empirical \\
\hhline{|>{\cb}->{\bk}|>{\cb}->{\bk}|>{\cb}->{\bk}|---}
\rowcolor{CadetBlue1!60!} & &\multirowcell{-3}{Post-water \\ breakthrough} & Suoza \& al. & Assumes the horizontal well traverses the entire drainage area, so flow beyond the ends of the well is neglected. & \cellcolor{Tan1!50!}Empirical \\
 \hhline{|>{\cb}->{\bk}|>{\cb}->{\bk}|----}
\rowcolor{CadetBlue1!60!} & & & Papatzakos \mbox{\& al.} & This solution applies only to infinite acting reservoirs. The solution is derived by a moving boundary method with constant pressure or gravity equilibrium assumed at the moving boundary. & \cellcolor{Tan1!50!}Empirical \\
\hhline{|>{\cb}->{\bk}|>{\cb}->{\bk}|>{\cb}->{\bk}|---}
\rowcolor{CadetBlue1!60!} & & & \mbox{Ozkan~\&} \mbox{Raghavan} & Developed using numerical simulation. This solution applies only to infinite acting reservoirs. & \cellcolor{Tan1!50!}Empirical \\
\hhline{|>{\cb}->{\bk}|>{\cb}->{\bk}|>{\cb}->{\bk}|---}
\rowcolor{CadetBlue1!60!} &\multirowcell{-12}{\colorbox{CadetBlue1!60!}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Oil-Water \& Gas-Water}}} & \multirowcell{-5}{Breakthrough\\ Time} & Suoza \& al. & Developed using numerical simulation, by correlating the results from many simulation runs. Assumes the horizontal well traverses the entire drainage area, so flow beyond the ends of the well is neglected. & \cellcolor{Tan1!50!}Empirical \\
\hhline{|>{\cb}->{\bk}|-----}
\rowcolor{CadetBlue1!60!} & & \multirowcell{3}{Critical Rate} & Chaperon & For horizontal wells, the method assumes that the well is drilled near the top of the reservoir for water coning situations. & \cellcolor{Tan1!50!}Empirical \\
\hhline{|>{\cb}->{\bk}|>{\cb}->{\bk}|>{\cb}->{\bk}|---}
\rowcolor{CadetBlue1!60!}\multirowcell{-16}{\colorbox{CadetBlue1!60!}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{{Horizontal}}}} & \multirowcell{-3}{\colorbox{CadetBlue1!60!}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Gas-Oil}}} & \multirowcell{-3}{Critical Rate} & Joshi & The Equations are for short horizontal wells. They are modifications of the Meyer, Gardner, Pirson method for vertical wells. & \cellcolor{Tan1!50!} Empirical \\
\Xhline{1pt}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Such tables are easy to produce in ConTeXt. As a proof of concept, I reproduce part of the table. I have not tried to match the colors to those given in the example.

```
\setuppapersize[A3]
\setupbodyfont[10pt]

\startsetups table:style
  \setupTABLE[column][3][width=3cm, align={middle,lohi}]
  \setupTABLE[column][4][width=3cm]
  \setupTABLE[column][5][width=12cm]
  \setupTABLE[column][6][width=2cm]

  \setupTABLE[align={lohi}, background=color]

  \setupTABLE[row][1][foregroundstyle=bold, align={middle,lohi}, backgroundcolor=gray]

  \setupTABLE[row][2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11][backgroundcolor=yellow]
\stopsetups

\defineframed
  [tightbox] 
  [
    align={middle,nothyphenated},
    width=fit,
    height=fit,
    frame=off,
  ]
\def\rotatebox#1{\rotate{\tightbox{#1}}}

\starttext

\bTABLE[setups=table:style]
  \bTR
     \bTD \rotatebox{Well~type}\eTD 
     \bTD \rotatebox{System}   \eTD 
     \bTD Calculated parameter \eTD 
     \bTD Author               \eTD 
     \bTD Limitation           \eTD 
     \bTD \rotatebox{Equation \\ type}        \eTD 
  \eTR

  \bTR
    \bTD[ny=10] \rotatebox{Vertical} \eTD
    \bTD[ny=8]  \rotatebox{Oil-Water~&~Gas-Water} \eTD
    \bTD[ny=5]  Critical Rate \eTD
    \bTD Chaperon \eTD
    \bTD For vertical wells, the perforated interval, hp, is very small and the well is perforated at the top of the reservoir for water coning situations. Analytical equations are based on the equilibrium conditions of viscous forces and gravity forces. \eTD
    \bTD[backgroundcolor=lightgreen] Analytical \eTD
  \eTR
  \bTR
    \bTD Hoyland et al \eTD
    \bTD Equations are based on correlation of computer simulation runs. \eTD
    \bTD[backgroundcolor=lightgreen] Empirical \eTD
  \eTR
  \bTR
    \bTD Meyer et al \eTD
    \bTD Equations are based on simplified radial flow of oil under it's own gravity head. They are generally less accurate than more rigorous methods. For gas coning, it is assumed that the gas-oil contact is depressed around the wellbore because of radial flow. For simultaneous gas and water coning, the maximum possible oil production rate is calculated assuming an optimum placement of the perforated interval. \eTD
    \bTD[backgroundcolor=lightgreen] Analytical \eTD
  \eTR
  \bTR
    \bTD Schols \eTD
    \bTD Equations are based on correlation of laboratory experiments. For oil mostly. \eTD 
    \bTD[backgroundcolor=lightgreen] Empirical \eTD
  \eTR
  \bTR
    \bTD Chirechi \eTD
    \bTD Based on the potentiometric theory of Muskat and Wyckoff using and electrical analog model. \eTD
    \bTD[backgroundcolor=lightred] Analytical \eTD
  \eTR

  \bTR
    \bTD  Post-water breakthrough \eTD
    \bTD Kuo & DesBrisay \eTD
    \bTD This correlation was developed by investigating the sensitivity of water coning performance to various reservoir parameters using numerical simulation. \eTD
    \bTD[backgroundcolor=lightred] Empirical \eTD
  \eTR

  % and so on.

\eTABLE

\stoptext
```

which gives the following:

[image]

Note that the code is relatively clean. The only trick part is that one has to explicitly use a `\rotatebox` macro. Normally, simply passing `orientation=90` to the `\bTD` macro should work, but for some reason it does not in this case. I'll try to see why that is happening.